`safeTransferFrom` fails although the contract has enough allowance
I'm creating a contract that calls to another contract to perform a swap. Here is the code for the function that does the work:
function swap(
        IERC20 baseToken,
        IERC20 quoteToken,
        uint256 inAmount,
        uint256 outAmount,
        address targetDex,
        bytes memory data,
        uint256 feeRate                                                                              
    ) public payable {
        require(
            (msg.value != 0) == baseToken.isETH(),
            "msg.value should be used only for ETH swap"
        );

        require(this.isMember(targetDex), "DEX is not supported");
        // save old value for validation later
        uint256 oldBalance = quoteToken.universalBalanceOf(address(this));
        if (!baseToken.isETH()) {
            baseToken.safeTransferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), inAmount);
        }

        if (baseToken.isETH()) {
            (bool ok,) = payable(targetDex).call{value: msg.value} (
                data
            );
            require(ok, "ETH swap failed");
        } else {
            _resetAllowances(baseToken, inAmount, targetDex);
            (bool ok,) = payable(targetDex).call{value: msg.value} (
                data
            );
            require(ok, "Subswap failed");
        }

        // calculate amount of token to be transfered to user

        uint256 newBalance = quoteToken.universalBalanceOf(address(this));
        uint256 received = newBalance.sub(oldBalance);
        uint256 actualSwapped = Math.min(
            outAmount,
            received 
        );
        uint256 fee = actualSwapped.mul(feeRate).div(10000);
        uint256 remaining = actualSwapped.sub(fee);
        quoteToken.transferFrom(address(this), msg.sender, remaining);
    }

    function _resetAllowances(IERC20 token, uint256 amt, address spenderAddress) internal
    {
        token.safeApprove(spenderAddress, uint256(0));
        token.safeIncreaseAllowance(spenderAddress, amt);
    }

However, even when I approved maximum values in my wallet to the smart contract, the transaction still fails at baseToken.safeTransferFrom. The SafeERC20 interface has a function _callOptionalReturn that throws error whenever being called.
Here are the failed transactions:
https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/0x51bbc037ab508c20cd94e5a1990775620677db92fcfd8aa0c781d703a7148770
https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/0x8402f4c9bebfe5b1bf31e65853109c7f867da22008cfb553e5023705f8d83e39
Here are information fed into the function:
{
     baseToken: 0xae13d989daC2f0dEbFf460aC112a837C89BAa7cd
     quoteToken: 0xBb843a2296F9AA49070EB2Dcd482f23548238f65
     inAmount: 100000000000000
     outAmount: 511579
     targetDex: 0x19395624C030A11f58e820C3AeFb1f5960d9742a
     data: 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
     feeRate: 1000
}

Could anyone explain why it throws the error? I really appreciate

This is not an allowance issue, the amount is greater than the balance. Recheck the balance.

